# Exchange Web Service PR_BODY_HTML null for HTML body

Tags: mime, exchangewebservices

I have an Exchange Web Services component that someone wrote a few years ago and has been working un-maintained since then, until an issue arose yesterday.

We have one specific email being sent from an external contractors system to our mailboxes. It is a HTML formatted email, but when I try the following:

```
EmailMessage em = item as EmailMessage
ExtendedPropertyDefinition htmlBody = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1013, MapiPropertyType.Binary); //PR_BODY_HTML=0x1013 ?)
em.TryGetProperty(htmlBody, out bodyHTMLBytes);
```

I get am getting a `null` response just for these specific emails. All other HTML-based emails are coming through just fine.

Are there any other ways we could be looking for a HTML body? The email renders just fine in Outlook and OWA.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a report item (delivery, non-delivery, receipt etc)? These do not have bodies (the body is composed "on the fly" by Outlook from RTF internal message data).